# SWIFT clicking the button app crashes

Tags: ios, swift, ibaction, sigabrt, unrecognized-selector

When I click on the button (which is connected to `@IBAction fun Plus(..)..)` my app crashes saying:

```
Thread 1: signal SIGABRT in AppDelegate.Swift file.
```

Here's what Xcode says:

```
`2015-05-05 00:43:11.165 koka[14911:632850] -[koka.ViewController mainButton:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fa4205786b0
2015-05-05 00:43:11.192 koka[14911:632850] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[koka.ViewController mainButton:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fa4205786b0'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000108615a75 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010a16dbb7 objc_exception_throw + 45
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010861cd1d -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 205
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001085749dc ___forwarding___ + 988
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000108574578 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    5   UIKit                               0x0000000108ea9a22 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 75
    6   UIKit                               0x0000000108fb0e50 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 467
    7   UIKit                               0x0000000108fb021f -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 522
    8   UIKit                               0x0000000108eefb68 -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 735
    9   UIKit                               0x0000000108ef0493 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 683
    10  UIKit                               0x0000000108ebcfb1 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 246
    11  UIKit                               0x0000000108eca227 _UIApplicationHandleEventFromQueueEvent + 17700
    12  UIKit                               0x0000000108ea523c _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 2066
    13  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010854ac91 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
    14  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000108540b5d __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 269
    15  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000108540194 __CFRunLoopRun + 868
    16  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010853fbc6 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 470
    17  GraphicsServices                    0x000000010c71ea58 GSEventRunModal + 161
    18  UIKit                               0x0000000108ea8580 UIApplicationMain + 1282
    19  koka                                0x000000010842fa6e top_level_code + 78
    20  koka                                0x000000010842faaa main + 42
    21  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000010a949145 start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

Here's my code. There is a lot of unnecessary information but, to make sure, I've posted all the code. You can see that the body of `@IBAction func Enter(..)..` is similar to the `@IBAction func Plus(..)..` one, but instead of Plus function first one works fine.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var num = ""
    var typedNum: [Int] = []
    var numArray: [[Int]] = []
    var numSumArray: [[Int]] = []
    var plusFlag = false
    var minusFlag = false
    var resultLabel = "Res: "
    var length: Int = Int()

    @IBOutlet weak var resultField: UILabel!

    @IBAction func Reset(sender: UIButton!) {
        resultLabel = "Res: "
        resultField.text = resultLabel
        num = ""
        plusFlag = false
        minusFlag = false
        numArray = []
        numSumArray = []
    }

    @IBAction func Enter(sender: UIButton!) {
        resultLabel += " = "
        numArray = getNum(num)
        length = numArray.count
        if (length == 1){
            resultLabel += num
        }
        resultField.text = resultLabel
        if (length > 1){
            if plusFlag{
                numSumArray[length-1] = SumOfTwo(numArray[length-2], second: numArray[length-1])
                for i in numSumArray{
                    resultLabel += "\(i)"
                }
            }
            if minusFlag{
            }
        }

        //reset
        resultLabel = "Res: "
        num = ""
        plusFlag = false
        minusFlag = false
        numArray = []
        numSumArray = []
    }

    @IBAction func Minus(sender: UIButton!) {

    }

    @IBAction func Plus(sender: UIButton!) {
        numArray = getNum(num)
        length = numArray.count
        if (length > 1){
            if plusFlag{
                numSumArray[length-1] = SumOfTwo(numArray[length-2], second: numArray[length-1])
                numArray[length-1] = numSumArray[length-1]
                plusFlag = false
            }
            if minusFlag{
            }
        }
        plusFlag = true
        resultLabel += " + "
        resultField.text = resultLabel
        num = ""
    }

    @IBAction func Null(sender: UIButton!) {
        num += "0"
        resultLabel += "0"
        resultField.text = resultLabel
    }

    @IBAction func One(sender: UIButton!) {
        num += "1"
        resultLabel += "1"
        resultField.text = resultLabel
    }

    @IBAction func Two(sender: UIButton!) {
        num += "2"
        resultLabel += "2"
        resultField.text = resultLabel
    }

    @IBAction func Three(sender: UIButton!) {
        num += "3"
        resultLabel += "3"
        resultField.text = resultLabel
    }

    @IBAction func Four(sender: UIButton!) {
        num += "4"
        resultLabel += "4"
        resultField.text = resultLabel
    }

    @IBAction func Five(sender: UIButton!) {
        num += "5"
        resultLabel += "5"
        resultField.text = resultLabel
    }

    @IBAction func Six(sender: UIButton!) {
        num += "6"
        resultLabel += "6"
        resultField.text = resultLabel
    }

    @IBAction func Seven(sender: UIButton!) {
        num += "7"
        resultLabel += "7"
        resultField.text = resultLabel
    }

    @IBAction func Eight(sender: UIButton!) {
        num += "8"
        resultLabel += "8"
        resultField.text = resultLabel
    }

    @IBAction func Nine(sender: UIButton!) {
        num += "9"
        resultLabel += "9"
        resultField.text = resultLabel
    }


    func getNum(num: String) -> [[Int]]{
        var i = 0
        for Character in num{
            let characterString = String(count: 1, repeatedValue: Character)
            typedNum.append(characterString.toInt()!)
            i++
        }
        numArray.append(typedNum)
        return numArray
    }

    func SumOfTwo(first: [Int], second: [Int]) -> [Int]{
        var perenos = 0
        var newValue: Int
        var newArray: [Int] = []
        for (index, value) in enumerate(first){
            newValue = value + second[index]
            perenos = newValue / 10
            newValue %= 10
            newArray[index] = newValue
        }
        return newArray
    }


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //let button = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.System) as UIButton
        //button.addTarget(self, action: "Plus", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

P.S. I tried to reconnect the button from **Main.storyboard** to **ViewController.Swift** but it didn't help. I didn't change **AppDelegate.Swift**

Comment: Which line of your IBAction is crashing?

Comment: initialisation of the AppDelegate class in AppDelegate.Swift

Comment: That doesn't make sense. The app delegate should not have IBAction methods. The app delegate does not have views associated with it. If you are having a crash in your app delegate, why did you post a bunch of code from your `ViewController` class?

Comment: because AppDelegate code is by default. I don't know why it crashes there and I think there is no need to show AppDelegate.Swift because, I will repeat, it's by default

Comment: What you say makes no sense.

Comment: OK then, what should I post?

Comment: Hmm, let me think. How about the line of code that's crashing, and the full method that contains that line? Indicate clearly which line is crashing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally, I found the answer! I deleted IBActions which were previously connected from Main.storyboard in: View Controller Scene -> Show the Connections Inspector

Answer (score 0):

Is "resultLabel" a label control? If it is just a variable (String) then it is OK (except you are using extremely bad naming technique), else wise look at every place in your program that you are using "resultLabel".

Comment: "resultLabel" is a string variable and I'm using it to edit label ("resultField") ;
I'm not sure that the problem connected with "resultLabel"

Comment: try this:      length = "\\(numArray.count)"        - you are trying to assign an Int to a string.

Comment: "length" is Int and how it can be assigned to String: "\(numArray.count)"..?